# why does the love-maths repository have a docker file unlike the others that show html?

Tags: html, github, dockerfile, repository

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PuW28.png)

Here is a link to my repositories: https://github.com/diegosno?tab=repositories

I'm not sure I've tried something other than create the love-maths repository from a template. I t's worth to mention that the other repositories were created from the same template as well.

Answer (score 0):

Github will evaluate the file types and lines of code and generate you a summary of the breakdown of your repo. For example in your math repo you can see that the most of the repo is from docker file. So thats why it shows on the front screen as dockerhub.

[image]

If we compare this to the code of health lifestyle repo, it has more html code in it and takes up a large percenatge of the code base in this repo cause it has more html files and code than the maths one.

[image]